# SQL Server stored procedure not work with varchar second parameter

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have written this procedure in SQL Server:

```
 ALTER  PROCEDURE [dbo].[buscapro1]
    @prod nvarchar(80), 
    @opc bit     
AS
    if @opc=1 
    begin
       select 
          idproduto, CODIGO, codfab, produto, Descricao, PRECOVENDA 
       from 
          verproduto 
       where 
          CODIGO like @prod
    end

    if @opc=2
    begin
       select 
           idproduto, CODIGO, codfab, produto, Descricao, PRECOVENDA 
       from 
           verproduto 
       where 
           produto like @prod 
   end
```

If I send this line :

```
  buscapro1 'bela-01', 1
```

I have rows with positive return. Now the problem is the second parameter "produto" returns empty

```
  select * 
  from verproduto 
  where produto like 'aparador'
```

returns

```
 idProduto  CODIGO   PRODUTO     Descricao  PRECOVENDA  TRATAMENTO
 -------------------------------------------------------------------------
  1480          BELA-01  APARADOR    Aparador      325          Bela Moveis
```

When I send

```
 buscapro1 'aparador',2
```

returns empty, what am I doing wrong?

Thanks alejandro

Answer (score 5, accepted):

BIT can only be 1 or 0, not 2; when you set it to 2, you actually get value of 1.

Answer (score 0):

`bit` can only take values 0,1 or null. 2 is an invalid value, so you might want to change second parameter (and the underlying column) to an `int` field instead.